# Compare and sum the items of identical keys

Tags: python, list, concatenation

So I have two lists, one is of the ingredients themselves in the form ['Cheese','Beans','Fish','Cheese',etc.] and the other is of the amounts [100,250,100,50,etc.]. What I now want is for like items in the ingredients list to be combined and like terms in the amounts list to be added.

What I need. Suppose I have amounts listed above (without the etc.'s) I would like the Ingredients list to become ['Cheese','Beans','Fish'] and the Amounts list to become [150,250,100]. Where the two 'Cheese' amounts have been added.

So far I have found the unique elements of the Ingredients, but don't know how to extract the index for arbitrarily large number of non-unique ingredients.

I need this to work for say
Ingredients = ['Cheese','Fish','Cheese','Eggs','Fish','Cheese'],
Amounts = [100,50,65,120,15,150],

Where the output would then be:
Ingredients = ['Cheese','Fish','Eggs'],
Amounts = [315,65,120].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initialization**

```
Ingredients = ['Cheese','Fish','Cheese','Eggs','Fish','Cheese']
Amounts = [100,50,65,120,15,150]
```

**Merging Ingredients by Amounts**

```
total = {}
for i, a in zip(Ingredients, Amounts):
    total[i] = total.get(i, 0) + a  # Accumulating by ingredient
```

**Output**

```
Ingredients = list(total.keys())
Amounts = list(total.values())

print(Ingredients)
print(Amounts)
```

---

```
['Cheese', 'Fish', 'Eggs']
[315, 65, 120]
```